# C# implementation of PushbackInputStream

Tags: c#

I need a C# implementation of Java's PushbackInputStream. I have made my own very basic one, but I wondered if there was a well tested and decently performing version already available somewhere. As it happens I always push back the same bytes I read so really it just needs to be able to reposition backwards, buffering up to a number of bytes I specify. (like Java's BufferedInputStream with the mark and reset methods).

**Update:** I should add that I can't simply reposition the stream as CanSeek may be false. (e.g. when the input steam is a [NetworkStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.canseek.aspx))

Answer (score 1):

The problem with pushing data back into a stream is that any readers that sit on *top* of the stream may already have a local buffer of data. This makes this approach very brittle. Personally, I would try to avoid this scenario, and use data constructs where I either don't need to push back, or can use single-byte Peek etc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to build a wrapper class that either functions as a stream, but supports a buffer of the last X bytes so you can seek back at least for a limited distance, or something that isn't a stream at all where you can indeed "push data back into the input stream".

Either way you're going to have to write something yourself.

Comment: well strictly speaking, I am just trying to reposition backwards in a stream that doesn't necessarily support seeking. Its a port of existing Java code that used both PushbackInputStream and BufferedInputStream, and I didn't want to have to completely redesign it.

Comment: PushbackInputStream and BufferedInputStream are both open source now and IIRC the licence would allow you taking the code, porting it to the c# Stream idiom and using it yourself but not distributing it. Would that do?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use a System.IO.Stream and seek backwards after reading from current position?

```
stream.Seek(-1, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Current)
```

Where -1 could be a variable of how far you want to go back?

Answer (score 0):

So long as the stream indicates it supports seeking (CanSeek) then

```
stream.Seek(-offset, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Current)
```

Will be fine.